# How can I render a React component in usual website

Tags: reactjs

How can I render a `React` component in my app?

I add these 3 lines in my `head` section:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and then my `component`:

```
<script type="text/jsx" src="/js/test-react.js"></script>
```

In `body` section I have block with the following `id`:

```
<div id="react-test"></div>
```

This is my  `react` `component`:

```
const el = document.getElementById("react-test");

const arr = [
  'One1',
  'One2',
  'One3',
  'One4',
  'One5',
]

class TestReactComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(porps) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isReady: true
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {arr.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <li>
              <a href="#">{item}</a>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul<
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestReactComponent/>, el);
```

I have no errors in my console but it does nothing at all. My block with `id` `react-test` is empty.

Comment: I think the problem is with your script type. Try  **type="text/babel"** instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ul` closing tag is not correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19750310)

Comment: @camille ¯\(°_o)/¯ It likely does answer the question, though.